# Intel Proset/Wireless Software fails to install

Tags: windows-7, wifi-driver

I have a samsung laptop with window 7 Home Premium. I wanted to update my WiFi driver coz previous version get corrupted. I downloaded the Intel Proset/Wireless Software 15.0.0.75 from Samsung website. When i execute the setup, installation did start. It continues for few mins then give error "iChain.exe has stop working" and the installation ends without completion.

please help